# Begginer in vim, set .vimrc for vim-Latex

Tags: vim, latex

I am a total beginner with Vim, but after a few years using Texmaker I would like to try Latex with Vim.
I tried to set up vim-Latex (for Ubuntu), but I am a bit lost...

Following the official doc, I put

```
filetype plugin on
set grepprg)grep\ -nH\ $*
filetype indent on
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
```

in my .vimrc
Then I ad

```
let g:Tex_FormatDependency_pdf = 'dvi,ps,pdf'
```

to compile a pdf file, and

```
let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf = 'okular'
```

to be able to visualize this file with okular.
But the compilation does not work and when I try to use "\lv" the .dvi file is opened, with evince, so nothing that I asked for..

Someone has an idea of what should I put in .vimrc ?

Comment: 1. The plugin you are using has an issue tracker, which you are expected to use if you have issues with it. 2. As a total beginner, you shouldn't be installing and configuring third-party plugins. There is a lot to learn first: `:help user-manual`.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot advise on vim-latex plugin, but I've been using vimtex for a while and I can share my config here: https://github.com/g6ai/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/vimrc The pdf viewer is skim, you could always change it to your liking.

There is also a wiki page for TeX in my dotfiles repo: https://github.com/g6ai/dotfiles/wiki/TeX You could also read some other info in that wiki, hope it helps

Comment: Oh thats is great, thanks a lot !! I just have a question : is it possible to use pdflatex to compile with vimtex ?

Comment: It uses latexmk mainly https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/wiki/introduction#latexmk